# Rock, Paper, Scissors in Functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I need to write rock, paper, scissors only using functions.

I have not done this before so my try at it is below. I am not able to get it to run fully through. Any pointers in the right direction would be very helpful!

Code below:

```py
import random 

def user_choice():
    user_choice = input("Choose rock, paper, or scissors: ")
    if user_choice in ["rock", "Rock"]:
        user_choice = "r"
    elif user_choice in ["paper", "Paper"]:
        user_choice = "p"
    elif user_choice in ["scissors", "Scissors"]:
        user_choice = "s"
    else: ("Try again.")
    user_choice
    return user_choice

def computer_choice():
    computer_choice = random.randint(1,3)
    if computer_choice == 1:
        computer_choice = "r"
    if computer_choice == 2:
        computer_choice = "p"
    if computer_choice == 3:
        computer_choice = "s"
    return computer_choice



def get_winner():
     
     #User choice = rock
    if user_choice == "r":
        if computer_choice == "r":
            print ("You and computer chose rock. It's a tie!")
    
    elif user_choice == "r":
        if computer_choice == "p":
            print ("You chose rock and computer chose paper. Computer wins!")
    
    elif user_choice == "r":
        if computer_choice == "s":
            print ("You chose rock and computer chose scissors. You win!")
    
    #User choice = scissors
    if user_choice == "s":
        if computer_choice == "s":
            print ("You and computer chose scissors. It's a tie!")
    
    elif user_choice == "s":
        if computer_choice == "p":
            print ("You chose scissors and computer chose paper. You win!")
    
    elif user_choice == "s":
        if computer_choice == "r":
            print ("You chose scissors and computer chose rock. Computer wins!")
    
    #User choice = paper
    if user_choice == "p":
        if computer_choice == "p":
            print ("You and computer chose paper. It's a tie!")
    
    elif user_choice == "p":
        if computer_choice == "r":
            print ("You chose paper and computer chose rock. You win!")
    
    elif user_choice == "p":
        if computer_choice == "s":
            print ("You chose paper and computer chose scissors. Computer wins!")
    else:
        print("Error")
  
user_choice()
computer_choice()
get_winner()
```

I tried writing a function for the user input, a random choice for the computer, and one that compares the user and computer choice to get the winner. I have tried writing and calling the functions but it is not working.

Comment: Saying "it is not working" does not help us find the problem.  If you're getting errors, or unexpected output, you have to show us.

Comment: Perhaps not helpful, but instead of using `if user_choice in ["rock", "Rock"]` you can use `if user.choice.lower() == "rock"` This will eliminate the possibility of something going wrong if the user were to type `"rOCK"` or `"ROCK"`

Comment: Note that your whole `computer_choice` function can be replaced by a single line: `return random.choice(['r', 'p', 's'])`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass results of "input" functions to "get_winner" function as arguments.

It should be defined like that:

```
def get_winner(user_choice, computer_choice):
```

Then in your code:

```
uc = user_choice()
cc = computer_choice()
get_winner(uc, cc)
```